# How to perform an action only when a state is changed?

Tags: arduino, state, state-machine, arduino-c++

Basically I want to make my IR led send **one** code when the Bluetooth connection state is `CONNECTED`. When the connection state becomes `DISCONNECTED`, the IR led should send a different code once. However, my code keeps sending one IR code continuously. When the Bluetooth state has changed, it keeps sending the other IR code continuously.

How can I change my code to only send one IR code every time the Bluetooth connection state changes?

```cpp
#include "BluetoothA2DPSink32.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <IRremoteESP8266.h>
#include <IRsend.h>

const uint16_t kIrLed = 2; 
IRsend irsend(kIrLed);
const uint16_t rawData[71] = {9004, 4556,  534, 602,  506, 654,  490, 624,  514, 1762,  490, 1764,  486, 1768,  516, 1762,  490, 626,  516, 622,  486, 1770,  514, 1762,  492, 1762,  486, 654,  490, 624,  514, 622,  486, 652,  490, 626,  514, 622,  488, 632,  512, 626,  512, 602,  532, 628,  490, 626,  514, 622,  486, 1770,  514, 1744,  510, 1742,  508, 1768,  516, 1762,  490, 1764,  512, 1744,  514, 1762,  492, 41344,  9022, 2298,  508};
const uint16_t rawData2[71] = {9022, 4574,  518, 622,  486, 654,  490, 628,  512, 1762,  490, 1764,  486, 1770,  514, 1762,  490, 626,  514, 622,  488, 1768,  514, 1762,  490, 1744,  506, 654,  490, 624,  516, 622,  486, 652,  492, 1764,  486, 1768,  516, 622,  488, 652,  490, 624,  516, 622,  488, 652,  490, 626,  514, 622,  488, 654,  490, 1764,  486, 1770,  514, 1762,  490, 1764,  486, 1770,  514, 1764,  490, 41360,  9006, 2318,  488};

BluetoothA2DPSink32 a2dp_sink;

void setup() {
  irsend.begin();
  a2dp_sink.set_bits_per_sample(32);  
  a2dp_sink.start("Hifi32bit");   
}

void loop() {
  if (a2dp_sink.get_connection_state()==ESP_A2D_CONNECTION_STATE_CONNECTED) {
    irsend.sendRaw(rawData, 71, 38);
  }

  if (a2dp_sink.get_connection_state()==ESP_A2D_CONNECTION_STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
    irsend.sendRaw(rawData2, 71, 38);
  }
}
```

Comment: show in the question the version with the state variable

Comment: I don't understand you, I talked about this state, full name is ESP_A2D_CONNECTION_STATE_CONNECTED, here is it's in code:

(a2dp_sink.get_connection_state()==ESP_A2D_CONNECTION_STATE_CONNECTED)

Comment: I meant this "I tried to put flag and use it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're performing the check continuously, and ***for every check*** you execute the `if`-statement in which you send the IR code. Consequently, your application will keep sending IR codes as fast as it can.

If you only want to send do something (send an IR code) on a state change, you should remember the state, and perform an action ***on a state change*** instead.

This is very easy to implement by adding a variable `previous_connection_state`. Example code below (this would replace the `loop()` from your current code).

```cpp
esp_a2d_connection_state_t previous_connection_state;

void loop() {
    esp_a2d_connection_state_t connection_state = a2dp_sink.get_connection_state();

    if (connection_state != previous_connection_state) {

        if (connection_state == ESP_A2D_CONNECTION_STATE_CONNECTED) {
            irsend.sendRaw(rawData, 71, 38);
        }

        if (connection_state == ESP_A2D_CONNECTION_STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            irsend.sendRaw(rawData2, 71, 38);
        }

        previous_connection_state = connection_state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank YOU so much for help! It works now! Your code is simple and elegant. I had issues with sending IR signal after implementing your code (receiver don't want to recognize first signal which sent on "Connected" status) but after i added delay in between two connections status reads it somehow started working. I also changed "get_connection_state" in second status read to "connection_state" (it's a typo?). It's  working  now. It maybe not 100% recognizing but its good. I will try to add power filter caps so maybe it will help completely eliminate not recognized codes.

Comment: @OppaYA, glad it helped :-) The second "get_connection_state" was a typo indeed. Fixed it now.